# Проблема с преобразованием битовой строки в десятичное число

Tags: java

Реализую генетический алгоритм,но при преобразовании некоторых строк в десятичное число выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111111111" under radix 2
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at ga.GA.main(GA.java:53)
C:\Users\Андрей\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Андрей\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Строка кода на которую ругается:

```
parentGenes[i]=Integer.parseInt(bitParentGenes[i],2);
```

С чем это связано? При том что ошибка не всегда.

Comment: Здесь ведь ровно 32 единицы, верно? Что если попробовать Long вместо Integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "11111111111111111111111111111111" under radix 2

Строка из 32 единиц - это максимальное беззнаковое `Integer`, в `Java` тип `Integer` знаковый, число не помещается в него. В данном случае вам поможет `Long.parseLong`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте вывести в бинарном виде максимальное число типа `int`

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Выведенная строка будет на один символ короче той, с которой у вас возникает проблема. Результат переполняет целое число. Либо тщательнее контролируйте входные данные, либо используйте более широкий тип переменных

```
Long.parseLong("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2);
```